# GSheets: Calculating difference in times in a 24 hour business

Tags: google-sheets

I'm trying to calculate the difference between a start time and a persons first action and the same for the end time and their last action.

My problem is due to having a 24 hour business I can't seem to figure out a **single formula** to cope with shift times and actions being anywhere in the 24 hour time frame.

[Example sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1gBfeN_coNdwPZag2piBHaX3gJBFrUmckH4w3FmYEIyk/edit?usp=sharing)

The start times are manually imputed as "06:00" format and the Actions are taken from a `Left("12/09/2017 19:08:25"),8` format.

Comment: Without an illustration of the data in the question itself, this question is unfortunately off-topic. We are very keen here that questions survive into the future, and it being reliant on an external spreadsheet that is likely to change or be deleted does not assist in that endeavour. Would you be able to show the crux of the data in the question (whilst keeping the link as well)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The data entry is bad. You need to enter start and end times with its date ( You could just format it as just time for presentation purposes). But dates have to entered in and should be there below the time. For example, One of the finish times is 00:00:00 , while the expected finish time is 23:00:00. We could assume that he worked one hour late and ended his shift by start of tomorrow. But spreadsheets cannot assume. It would think that he finished by `today` morning 00:00:00 instead of his actual finish time `tomorrow` morning 00:00:00. So he went off early by 23 hours. Once that's fixed, You could simply find the difference between the two times. But, You have to format that column as number>`Duration` instead of `Time`.

To sum up,

- Add dates to start and end times
- Format the resulting difference column as Number>Duration.

Comment: Hmmm.  You have a valid point.  I don't control the manual input but I do maintain the form so I've changed it to grab the date to compare it to the system generated data.  Solved if being forced to realise i'm very lazy is solved.  Thanks.